# OpenLDAP auditlog does not take effect

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, ubuntu-14.04, openldap

I enabled the audit log for olcDatabase={1}hdb, while nothing is written back to the audit log after I add one entry to the ldap server.

1) Unbutu 14.0.4

```
# uname -a
Linux 2c31d748-c6b5-460d-ac5d-38c8ede8845f 3.19.0-56-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:03:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2) module is added to cn=module{0},cn=config

2.1)add module

```
     #cat loadModule.ldif
     #Load the auditlog modules.
     dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
     changetype: modify
     add: olcModuleLoad
     olcModuleLoad: auditlog.la
```

2.2) verify

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config cn=module{0} |grep -v "#"
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0

dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}back_hdb
olcModuleLoad: {1}syncprov
olcModuleLoad: {2}accesslog
olcModuleLoad: {3}auditlog
olcModuleLoad: {4}auditlog.la
```

3) add auditlog

3.1)

```
# cat auditlog.ldif
dn: olcOverlay=auditlog,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditLogConfig
olcOverlay: auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /tmp/auditlog.ldif
```

3.2 ) verify:

```
 # ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config olcOverlay={2}auditlog |grep -v "#"
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0

dn: olcOverlay={2}auditlog,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {2}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /tmp/auditlog.ldif

dn: olcOverlay={1}auditlog,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {1}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /var/log/slapd/auditlog.out
```

search: 2
result: 0 Success

4) add one entry and nothing is written back to the audit log

```
# ldapadd -x -h localhost -D cn=admin,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com -w password -f tester01.ldif
adding new entry "cn=tester01,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com"

root@2c31d748-c6b5-460d-ac5d-38c8ede8845f:~# ls -l /tmp/auditlog.ldif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 openldap openldap **0** Aug  8 23:59 /tmp/auditlog.ldif
```

Comment: Works for me. Just like that, except that I don't have the full pathname of the `olcAuditLogFile`, just `auditlog.ldif`, and it goes in the OpenLDAP installation directory. Note that these files can get enormous if not trimmed regularly: I just trimmed 300MB off mine, which has been running on a low-activity server for several years without trimming. I note that you ended up with two audit logs: are you running two databases?

Comment: The 2nd was added to when I was debugging. {1}hdb is the db storing the data. {2}hdb is actually the accesslog db.

Comment: @EJP, how do you load auditlog module?

olcModuleLoad: auditlog

OR

olcModuleLoad: auditlog.la

Comment: I don't have it at all, as my port has it linked in, but the [syntax](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release&format=html) states it is either a simple or a full filename, not a module name, so `auditlog.la` would be correct, assuming that is the filename and it is in the expected place.